# Series of Variables by name

Tags: autohotkey

In AHK script:

Code for finding a value between great numbers of variables above, for one variable:

```
If (Variable1 = "sin (90°)")
    MsgBox Value is reached
```

How searching by this method between series of variables with different value of number in their names? From Variable5 to Variable15, Variable51 to Variable105, etc.

How modify this code if number from 5 to 15, 51 to 105, or 74 to 117 etc?

```
number = 5
If (Variable%number% = "sin (90°)")
    .............
```

Is %Variable%number%% acceptable and will works surely?

And here may also be useful Associative Arrays. What is it by simple examples?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice here would probably be to use an array in the first place.

```
myArray := []
myArray[1] := "bla"
myArray.Push("bla2") ;by using this you don't need to worry about the index number
myArray[3] := "sin (90°)"
myArray[4] := 63456

Loop % myArray.MaxIndex() 
{
    If (myArray[A_Index] = "sin (90°)")
    {
        MsgBox Value is reached
    }
}
```

... another example

```
anotherArray := []

Loop, read, C:\Files\prog.txt
{
    If (A_LoopReadLine = "FileRead, OutputVar, C:\Files\prog1.txt")
    {
        anotherArray.Push(A_LoopReadLine)
        MsgBox, An interesting code line was found. And was added to the array.
    }
    Else If (A_LoopReadLine = "blablabla")
    {
        anotherArray.Push(A_LoopReadLine)
        MsgBox, An interesting code line was found. And was added to the array.
    }
    Else If (A_LoopReadLine = "some other text line")
    {
        anotherArray.Push(A_LoopReadLine)
        MsgBox, An interesting code line was found. And was added to the array.
    } 
    ;Else
    ;{
    ;    MsgBox, Nothing important was found.
    ;}
}

Loop % anotherArray.MaxIndex() 
{
    currentArrayEntry := anotherArray[A_Index]
    MsgBox, %currentArrayEntry%
}
```

Comment: Hm, I haven't actually tried it with array fields before. I'll look into it later..

Comment: Thanks! It probably has lot of sence. When I'll know what is an array I'll try understand this.

Answer (score 0):

In an *expression* you can use variable expansion to modify the name of the variable to use:

```
number = 5
If (Variable%number% = "sin (90°)")
    .............
```

But consider using [arrays](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/Arrays.htm) instead.

Comment: But outside of an expression? Is %Variable%number%% absolutely acceptable and will works surely everywhere?

Comment: Good script! It close to my question. And how modify this code if number from 5 to 15, 51 to 105, or 74 to 117 etc.

Comment: @BookNote, add more of your code into the original question, otherwise how can I help you?

Comment: And where's *your code that creates those variables*?

Answer (score 0):

> Is %Variable%number%% acceptable and will works surely?

Not. More right way

```
% Variable%number%
```

but it may have a problem.

Possible way is use Var := expression

```
Variable:= number
```

may be.